# Laravel 5.1 - Generate a unique 10 alphanumeric character code upon save to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, uniqueidentifier

I'm working in Laravel 5.1 and saving a gecko to a database. My code for my `store` method is below:

```
public function store(GeckoRequest $request)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $input = $request->all();

    $input['genetics'] = json_encode($input['genetics'], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    $input['user_id'] = $user_id;

    Gecko::create($input);

    $name = str_replace(' ', '-', $request['name']);

    flash()->success('Success!', 'Your gecko has been added to the system');
    return redirect()->action('GeckoController@show', [$name]);

}
```

I know I could do `$input['uid'] = str_random(10);` - But how do I *ensure* it is in fact unique and won't redirect back to my form if it isn't unique?

Is there a proper practice into achieving something like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a function that generates the 10 digit random key then passes it through a validator with a unique rule set. If the validator gives you an error re-run the same function to generate a new one

```
public function randomId(){

     $id = \Str::random(10);

     $validator = \Validator::make(['id'=>$id],['id'=>'unique:table,col']);

     if($validator->fails()){
          return $this->randomId();
     }

     return $id;
}
```

Comment: I need to test the other versions, but this does work. Will get back to you soon

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, you could achieve this using a created event on the model. This will allow you to add anything to the model before it is persisted in the database without any further interaction required.

In a service provider, or your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` add the event to the boot method.

```php
public function boot()
{
    User::creating(function ($user) {
        // When ever a User model is created
        // this event callback will be fired.
        $user->setAttribute('randomString', str_random(10));

        // Returning 'false' here will stop the
        // creation of the model.
    });
}
```

[Full documentation for eloquent model events.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I've used before:

```
  do
  {
      $code = // generate your code
      $gecko_code = Gecko::where('code', $code)->first();
  }
  while(!empty($gecko_code));
```

Comment: Would this be placed in the controller? Do i need to do anything else for this to save to the field?